# Is this a cast iron or metal toilet flange?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, flange

I'm going to use Set-Rite flange kit to bring up the height, but the instructions say to use a wax ring for cast iron or the included rubber gasket for metal. Not sure which method to use. My tubing is ABS, but the flange is metallic. Could this be a cast iron flange?

I did see a youtube video where the guy used the wax ring method even with a plastic flange, is that better than the flimsy rubber gasket?

[image]

Comment: Pretty weird instructions. Obviously cast iron **is** a metal.

Comment: The Set-Rite Flange Kit instructions I find online say to use both. The foam rubber gasket goes down 1st onto the existing flange, then the spacer, then the flange extender. A new wax ring then goes on top of the whole assembly.

Comment: Sure looks like cast iron to me.  Including all the rust.  How'd you get all the "mud" under the toilet base?

Comment: Cast iron is magnetic. Not sure what other metal it might be . If very old ,possibly lead

Comment: @FreeMan ok  . . .

Comment: And now you get a +1, @brhans! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [Set-Rite Flange Kit instructions](https://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/0f73d793-71d2-4e12-94b6-273df3bdf508/47522997.pdf?_gl=1*17affii*_gcl_au*MzI4NDgzNTQ5LjE2ODczNjY0MDU.) I find online say to use both the foam-rubber gasket and a new wax ring (not included in the kit).

The foam rubber gasket goes down 1st onto the existing flange, then the red plastic spacer (choose the one with the appropriate height), then the yellow plastic flange extender.
Lastly, a new wax ring goes on top of the whole assembly.

So the foam-rubber gasket  is only intended to seal the interface between the existing flange and the spacer/extender assembly.
The wax ring on top seals between the toilet and the flange extender, just as it would normally seal between the toilet and the original flange.

[image]
<sub>Extract from linked instruction sheet</sub>